# Windows 8.1 Apps not Compiling

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, windows-store

Recently, I needed to refresh my Windows 8.1 PC, and now that I have finally finished getting all of my programs reinstalled and everything is back to normal, I am ready to finish work on my Windows 8.1 app, but I am having an issue with compiling my apps. Every time I try to compile, I get the following error.

[image: Visual Studio 2013 Windows 8.1 App Compile Error]

Now normally when I need to refresh my developer licesnse, Visual Studio tells me, but this time I didn't get any prompt at all, and that is the error that I got when trying to compile. How can I fix this? I am installing updates for Visual STudio at the moment, and I am hoping that doing so will somehow magically fix the problem, but I am also aware that it probably won't.

**EDIT:** Now that I have updated, the message has been shortened to "Can't resolve Windows.metadata."

Comment: Did you try downloading the suggested SDK? Also which version of visual studio are you running?

Comment: @MarkHall Please excuse my ignorance, but where can I get the suggested SDK?

Comment: See the rest of my question also. The link was part of the original error message you posted

Comment: @MarkHall I am running Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate. Also, the link that was given in the error was for retargeting the app for 8.1, which I did before refreshing my PC.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, even though the Windows 8.1 SDK is supposed to be installed with Visual Studio Ultimate 2013, it wasn't for me. I was able to find the Windows 8.1 SDK by Googling it, and it came up as the top result. I installed it, and suddenly all of my errors went away and Visual Studio started recognizing them as legitimate Windows 8.1 app code.